# Job' retryUntil function doesn't seems to work as expected

Tags: laravel

I have this job which uses [retryUntil](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#time-based-attempts)

```php
class ExampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('oops');
    }

    public function retryUntil()
    {
        return now()->addSeconds(5);
    }
}
```

When I run this job I am expecting that, when it fails it will run again and again until 5 seconds are over. But what it only runs one time. why?

[image]

Comment: Have your set your tries in your config and or on your job?